# 3D maps library for android

Tags: android, 3d, maps

Does anybody know any free of charge android maps library that has 3D capabilities? 
I know for sure that google maps doesn't support 3d when using the sdk library.

The provider is not a problem. I'm not married with google maps, nor any other.

The following are apps that can be used as example of what i'm trying to accomplish.

Waze
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waze

Route 66
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.route66.maps5

Example
[image: i.stack.imgur.com/g8UXU.png]

Comment: ***I know for sure that google maps doesn't support 3d  when using sdk library***  [Are you sure?](http://www.google.com/mobile/maps/3d/)

Comment: Yes i'm sure. You pointed the Google Maps android app, which has way more features than the Google maps SDK library available for apps to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this question becomes obsolete now that we have the Google Maps Api V2 is out in the wild. Thanks everyone for taking your time to answer it.

Here's a quick release changelog

> The API is now distributed as part of the Google Play services SDK, which you can download with the Android SDK Manager. To learn how to install the package, see Installing the Maps API SDK.
>
> Maps are now encapsulated in the MapFragment class, an extension of Android's Fragment class. Now you can add a map as a piece of a larger Activity. With a MapFragment object, you can show a map by itself on smaller screens, such as mobile phones, or as a part of a more complex UI on larger-screen devices, such as tablets.
>
> Because maps are encapsulated in the MapFragment class, you can implement them by extending the Android standard Activity class, rather than extending the MapActivity used in version 1.
>
> The Maps API now uses vector tiles. Their data representation is smaller, so maps appear in your apps faster, and use less bandwidth.
>
> Caching is improved, so users will typically see a map without empty areas.
> Maps are now 3D. By moving the user's viewpoint, you can show the map with perspective.

[Here's the new API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

[Here's the Android Developers blog spot announcing the new API](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.ar/2012/12/better-maps-in-your-android-apps.html)

[And here's a screenshot of one of the new API early adopters Trulia](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-X9mYMEj_pNg/ULxApjNJeAI/AAAAAAAAHIw/3ZiZVS9LjAY/s640/Trulia+Screenshot.png)

[image]

Comment: Is there a provider for offline maps and 3d capabilities?

Comment: @usman You can write your own providers for offline 2D tiles, but AFAIK not 3D data.

Comment: Can you please give me more information about last link.It is dead

Answer (score 6):

I want to mention this solution:
http://www.eegeo.com

[image]

It is crossplatform service with 3D modelling,  routes tracking, traffic visualizing and a lot of other cool stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a 3D globe visualisation, you can use [Gesium](http://cesiumjs.org/). Here is [Hello World example](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/HelloWorld.html).

[image]

Comment: pretty sure the original question for an android app. Although Cesium is great and can run in a web view, it's not very stable in that environment

Answer (score 1):

We do provide one: [Nutiteq 3D Maps SDK](http://nutiteq.github.com/hellomap3d/). This is SDK, not an application.

[image: Nutiteq SDK 2.0 sample]

Comment: I guess i didn't mention that I will need an free of charge library.