# android 3d world map similar to google earth

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]

I saw this app named Geo Challenge on playstore and would like to develop one for my school project. Basically what I wanted to develop is a country quiz game. It is similar to google maps but on 3d. More like google earth. I wanted to develop on google maps but sadly it needs internet connection. Same functionality as to google maps if possible that can put pins on. Would some kind enough suggest any api available for this? Thanks alot.

Comment: You probably need to use OpenGL for this.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for giving your time for answering! Is it difficult learning opengl? I am really a beginner.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997098/3d-maps-library-for-android), and also you can learn `OpenGL` form [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS8wlS9hF8E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discuss, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997098/3d-maps-library-for-android) for `3D maps library for android`

Also, you can learn `OpenGL` [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS8wlS9hF8E).