# 3D Maps in android apps

Tags: android, google-maps

I Have some question about 3D Maps in apps.
I know JAVA very well, but i have never tried to build some Android app,and i think now its the best time to start :).
So, my question is, How can i build some 3D Map ? (For example the map in 'Pokemon go' or 'Waze').
I know that this is kind of funny question,Its a project that can takes years, so i will be more specific,What should i study to be able to make something similar ?
What should i study to integrate flash(?) parts in my future app ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my misunderstanding in apps development.

Answer (score 1):

You can start to read the [Camera and View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views) part of the Google Maps Android API to know how to view the 3D maps in your created maps.

For creating the 3D maps, you can follow this tutorial:

- [Android 3D Map SDK getting started](http://nutiteq.github.io/hellomap3d/)
- [OpenStreetMap building geometry on 2D and 3D maps](https://github.com/OSMBuildings/OSMBuildings)
- [3D maps library for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997098/3d-maps-library-for-android)

If you encounter different errors or need some idea when doing this, then I think you can go back here in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-maps%5D%2C+%5B3D%5D) to search or ask that question of yours.

Goodluck in creating your application and Happy coding :)